# Panel gets hidden on web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

on localhost its fine but on the webhost it gets hidden I can't figure it out.

[image: Local Host]

This is the url where its hidden: EDIT: Removed url...

[image: Online]

Comment: you are getting two script errors on the page_load of basket with an item in it. i dont think anybody could help you further with that. which framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using asp.net. where do u see the errors and why is it working perfact from visual studio/localhost?

Comment: at firebug. i was asking the version of framework actually. both at the development server and the production server

Comment: You will need to add more details, especially code, so others can assist you.

Comment: What browser? Works fine for me in FF 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is an unclosed html comment tag. Look for the following text in the source of your page:

```
<!--
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_contentPlaceHolder_rightProductsAccessoriesControl_notFoundMessagePanel">

</div>

<!--
```

You'll see that there is an opening comment tag `<!--` before the div, and after it, instead of a closing tag `-->` there is another opening tag. Which basically comments out the whole bottom part of your page until it hits another html comment section that closes it off. This also causes a script error because the ASP.NET validator code cannot find the validator control.

It works in FF because its parser seems to realize you made a mistake and stops it from commenting out the rest of the page. IE does not help you like this.

Answer (score 1):

Check your html code is formatted properly.
Close all tags and check for overlapping of tags incorrectly.